# Java Jdbc Transaction

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I have a requirement to execute sequence of select,update,insert queries in jdbc.

here is my code:

```
 public String editRequest(){
connection = DatabaseUtil.getServiceConnection();
            try {
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                executeUpdateCategory(category, ticketid);
                executeUpdateSubCategory(subcategory,
                        ticketid);
                executeUpdateItem(item, ticketid));
                executeUpdateImpact(impact),ticketid));
                  connection.commit();
                 response = "Success";
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                rollback();
            }
    return response;
    }
```

Method Definitions:

```
    public void executeCategory(category,ticketid){
        try{
        //select query using connection and prepared statement

        }
        catch(SQLException e){
        e.printstacktrace();
        }

etc... methods
```

Note:Since it is a single transaction.So if we get any exception inside the methods it is executing some of the statements.it is calling `commit()` method.

But these methods are reusable.Could any one how to catch the Exception inside editRequest method catch block so that i can rollback the transaction if any error?

Comment: You will have to use the same connection object if you wish to manage the transaction using connections, That in turn means you will have to pass the connection object to each of the methods in the transaction.

Comment: Do not catch exсeption in executeCategory(), just declare throws SQLException

Comment: @ramp It looks like `connection` is a member, then it works...

Comment: @Uwe, you are right. I did not notice that its an instance variable.

Comment: You marked this method with [spring] so why aren't you using that? Use a `JdbcTemplate` and a properly configured `DatasourceTransactionManager` and make your method `@Transactional`. This simplifies your code, get logging and automatic transactional behavior...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: Rethrow the exception.

Example:

```
public void executeCategory(category, ticketid) throws SQLException {
    try {
        //select query using connection and prepared statement
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

So you can log the exception at the place where it occurs and throw it again to `rollback()`.

**An alternative** (*perhaps the better one*) is to create a custom exception and rollback on this custom exception:

```
public void executeCategory(category, ticketid) throws CustomException {
    try {
        //select query using connection and prepared statement
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new CustomException(e);
    }
}
```

and in your calling code:

```
public String editRequest() {
connection = DatabaseUtil.getServiceConnection();
    try {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        executeUpdateCategory(category, ticketid);
        // Further calls
        connection.commit();
        response = "Success";
    } catch (CustomException e) {
        rollback();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Wrap and re throw (second example) would be better than re throwing (first example) the exception that has just been caught. You will get more information that way.

Comment: @redge Thanks for the comment. Changed the answer to make it clear that this is the better variant. The first variant is simply the answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch the SQLException in editRequest you need to let it propagate by adding a throws clause to each method and removing the try catch block.

Alternately you can catch the exception and wrap it in another exception that is thrown and caught in editRequest